# Is there an database connectivity framework or library for PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection

I wonder if there's a useful library or lightweight framework only for database connectivity. What I need is something that lets me use a MySQL database with prepared statements in a secure way, without thinking a lot about gcc_magic_quotes and stuff like that. Something object oriented would be nice to have, with some convenience when fetching data from the DB. I don't want to employ a giant framework like cake or symfony just for that. It should be something really lightweight, just for this purpose.

Please, if you recommend something, write a little about it's pros and cons. That would be great! Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: +1 PDO is the right way to go.

Answer (score 4):

MySQLi (note the i) supports prepared statements and it comes installed in most modern versions of PHP.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out
[Pear MDB2](http://pear.php.net/package/MDB2)

Answer (score 3):

PDO, MysqlI, PEAR MDB2, Doctrine(provides a lot more), ADO for PHP.  There are a lot of options, but I would probably use PDO.

Answer (score 1):

I use [this one](http://www.troywolf.com/articles/php/class_db/) by Troy Wolf since years. Never failed me.

Comment: Troy Wolf pointed out ADOdb. Looks great!!

Answer (score 0):

You can try my [database wrapper](https://github.com/salebab/database), it extends PDO and have some nice features.